# Getting S3 public policy using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I want to get the bucket policy for the various buckets. I tried the following code snippet(picked from the boto3 documentation):

```
conn = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket_policy=conn.BucketPolicy('demo-bucket-py')
print(bucket_policy)
```

But here's the output I get :

```
s3.BucketPolicy(bucket_name='demo-bucket-py')
```

What shall I rectify here ? Or is there some another way to get the access policy for s3 ?

Comment: added a method in solution to conifgure your programmatic keys for boto and aws cli, its sleek and definitely better when developing :),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked for me

```
import boto3

# Create an S3 client
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

# Call to S3 to retrieve the policy for the given bucket
result = s3.get_bucket_policy(Bucket='my-bucket')
print(result)
```

to perform this you need to configure or mention your keys like this `s3=boto3.client("s3",aws_access_key_id=access_key_id,aws_secret_access_key=secret_key)`. **BUT there is much better way to do this is by using `aws configure` command and enter your credentials.** for setting up [docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.42/guide/quickstart.html#configuration). Once you set up you wont need to enter your keys again in your code, boto3 or aws cli will automatically fetch it behind the scenes .https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html.

you can even set [different profiles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-profiles.html) to work with different accounts

Answer (score 1):

Try `print(bucket_policy.policy)`. More information on that [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#bucketpolicy).

Comment: botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (NoSuchBucketPolicy) when calling the GetBucketPolicy operation: The bucket policy does not exist
this error comes when I made the changes. Changes the settings of the bucket on the console,yet the same

Comment: Can you provide the policy that is currently on the bucket?

Comment: If there isn't a policy present, boto3 will through the NoSuchBucketPolicy exception.

Comment: If that answer helped you, would you be so kind to accept it?